# Circulant matrix equivalent to a unitary and diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

We have that $C_n\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a circulant matrix of order n. So we have $$
C_n =
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_0     & \alpha_{n-1} & \dots  & \alpha_{2} & \alpha_{1}  \\
\alpha_{1} & \alpha_0    & \alpha_{n-1} &         & \alpha_{2}  \\
\vdots  & \alpha_{1}& \alpha_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
\alpha_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & \alpha_{n-1}   \\
\alpha_{n-1}  & \alpha_{n-2} & \dots  & \alpha_{1} & \alpha_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we need to determine $Q_n$ and $\Gamma_n$ such that $$C_n = Q_n\Gamma_n Q_n^{H}$$ where $Q_n\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a unitary matrix and $\Gamma_n\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix.

It seems to me that since $Q_n$ is a unitary matrix, then isn't $Q_n Q_n^{H}$ just equal to the identity matrix? If that is the case then we just need to find a diagonal matrix $\Gamma_n$?

I am not sure on this, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that the columns of $Q$ must be (left) eigenvectors of $C_n$. Note that we are diagonalizing the matrix $C_n$.

Comment: The real trick here is that we can set $Q$ to be the DFT matrix (or possibly it's $Q^H$ that's the DFT matrix; haven't checked which).

Comment: How would you know which one is which? Since you are asked to find $Q_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to the following: set $Q_n$ equal to $F_n$, the DFT matrix (as you defined it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612070/81360)).

> **Note:** for the rest of the question, I stop using the subscript $n$, so $Q_n$ is just $Q$. Also, I continue to use notation from the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612070/81360).

First, notice that when $C = Z$, we indeed find that $Z = F\Gamma_Z F^H$, where
$$
\Gamma_Z = 
\pmatrix{1 \\ & \omega \\ && \ddots \\ &&& \omega^{n-1}}
$$ 
Now, for an arbitrary circulant $C$, let $f_C(x) = \sum_k \alpha_k x^k$ denote the associated polynomial of $C$. We note that $C = f_C(Z)$.  A neat consequence of this is that
$$
C = f_C(Z) = f_C(F\Gamma_Z F^H) = 
\sum_k \alpha_k (F\Gamma_Z F^H)^k = \\
\sum_k \alpha_k F\Gamma_Z^k F^H = 
F\left(\sum_k \alpha_k \Gamma_Z^k \right)F^H = \\
Ff_C(\Gamma_Z)F^H
$$
Moreover, because $\Gamma_Z$ is diagonal, we have the neat result
$$
f_C(\Gamma_Z) = 
\pmatrix{f_C(1) \\ & f_C(\omega) \\ && \ddots \\ &&& f_C(\omega^{n-1})}
$$
So, setting $Q$ equal to $F$ diagonalizes any circulant matrix $C$.

---

As for part iii of your original query, $C$ is non-singular if and only  if $f_C(\omega^k)\neq 0$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$.

There are more efficient, equivalent ways to check this condition assuming your $C_n$ is a real matrix, but this certainly does the job.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure if you know how to do this. But have you ever worked with C++ and initialized a complex matrix before?

Comment: I have not... I know numpy handles that stuff pretty easily though.

Comment: So we first set $Q_n = F_n$ and notice that $C_n = Z_n$ and we found in another problem that $Z_n = F_n\Lambda_n F_n^{H}$ where $\Lambda_n$ is also a diagonal matrix. So, essentially we see that $\Gamma_n = \Lambda_n$ why do we have to continue after this?

Comment: @Wolfy I think that if that were all that I had said, you would have been pretty confused.  The trick here is unpacking what "$\Gamma_n$ is essentially the same as $\Lambda_n$" is supposed to mean.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your statement. What do you mean?

Comment: Let me ask you this: what do **you** mean by "So, essentially we see that $\Gamma_n = \Lambda_n$"?

Comment: Actually, I seem to have misunderstood what you were saying.  I have no idea what you're going for.  How does your comment address *any circulant matrix* $C_n$?

Comment: So in a previous problem we showed that $Z_n = F^H \Lambda_n F$ where $\Lambda\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix. Since $Z_n = C_n$ then $\Gamma_n = \Lambda_n$.

Comment: Right, so that *specifically* handles the case of $Z = C$.  The question, however, is what do we do if $C$ is an **arbitrary** circulant matrix.  There are some circulant matrices that aren't equal to $Z$.

Comment: I see ok thanks I will try to understand your solution for that more, sort of struggling grasping your solution.

Comment: An important piece of the puzzle is that $C = f_C(Z)$; maybe that's what you're missing.

Comment: I think I see that since $\alpha_1 = 1$. If you think I'm not getting it do you have any references or books I could refer to?

Comment: The point of the question is to show that the statement is true no matter which values $\alpha_i$ you pick. Is that not clear?

Comment: Yes, I see that. Is there more information that shows $C = F_C(Z)$ or is it obvious and I just fail to see it?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's obvious.  But, if you try finding $f_C(Z)$ for an example or two, you should see the pattern.

Comment: As in let $n=4$ and try to find $f_C(Z_4)$?

Comment: Yes, and choose values for $\alpha_i$.  For example, $\alpha_0 = 1, \alpha_1 = 2, \alpha_2 = 3, \alpha_3 = 4$.  See what you get and why you get it.

Comment: We are plugging in these $\alpha_i$'s into the matrix $C$ right or is it $Z$ I am sort of confused finding what $f_C(Z)$ is :(

Comment: I guess what I am saying I am confused how to interpret the function $f_C(Z)$

Comment: Should I make a new question that links this so that I can understand how to use the function you defined?

Comment: So for my example, it would be $$f_C(Z_4)=I + 2Z_4 + 3Z_4^2 + 4 Z_4^3$$

Comment: If that doesn't make sense make a new question

Comment: Never mind I totally understand it now sorry for my slowness

Comment: Just one last question how did you think of doing it this way?

Comment: "I wonder what they expect us to do with the associated polynomial. What happens if we plug in $Z$? Oh, well that's it then."